# On functions whose derivative equals zero almost everywhere

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $f: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous everywhere and differentiable almost everywhere in $[0,1]$, and $f'(x)=0$ whenever the derivative exists. Is it true that 
$f(x)$ equals a constant?

It seems like the answer should be yes. However, I'm having trouble finding a version of the fundamental theorem of calculus which would apply to $f$.

Comment: Did you intend for it to be continuous *everywhere*?

Comment: Yes, continuous everywhere.

Comment: @KarlHaskell The devil's staircase or Cantor's function is  a counterexample to your question.

Comment: as for the fundamental theorem of calculus part of your question, you should read about "absolute continuity"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

More dramatically, the Cantor Singular Function $f$ is  increasing, continuous,  $f' = 0$, a.e, $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function

Comment: It is not *strictly* increasing